NetCDF to ASCII raster file with terra R package: differences in values
I used the terra R package to convert a NetCDF file (file.nc) to a ASCII raster file (file.asc):
library(terra)

raster <- rast("file.nc")
writeRaster(raster, "file.asc")

However, the resulting ASCII raster file has differences in its values in relation to the original NetCDF file, as their respective min and max values are different.
The NETCDF file contains environmental data and its source is Bio-Oracle, while the ASCII raster file will be used in SDM with MaxEnt. The variables are time, lat, lon, seawater temperature. Dimensions are 1 (time), 3600 (lat) and 7200 (lon), and the resolution is 0.05 degrees. The extent is global.
Any suggestions?

How little is the difference? If it's less than the 3rd decimal place it's likely to be due to the difference between floating point storage vs numbers as text.

As an example, bottom temp in oC: NetCDF -2 to 30.568766, ASCII -2 to 32,976873, so the difference in max T was in fact quite large

Is that just the statistics or have the pixel values changed? Are both datasets in the same coordinate system? Resampling from one CRS to another will cause values to change and if you're using bilinear or cubic resampling methods values can change significantly. Try subtracting one from the other, thresholding by a very small value (1.0e-4 perhaps) and look at where changes have occurred.
